# Storm Trident - Continuous emits from aggregator even when there is no data in kafka

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I have a topology which sources tuples from kafka.

Topology looks roughly like this.

```
topology.newStream("kafkaSpout", spout)
            .shuffle()
            .each(new Fields("str"), new Filter())
            .parallelismHint(5)
            .each(new Fields("str"), new Function(),
                  new Fields("some fields"))
            .parallelismHint(5)
            .partitionBy(new Fields("some field"))
            .partitionAggregate(new Fields("some fields"), 
                                new SomeAggregator(), 
                                new Fields(""some fields""))
            .parallelismHint(5)
            .partitionPersist(new StateFactory(),
                              new Fields("some filed"),
                              new StateUpdater());
```

> From documentation what I understand is that in the aggregator the aggregate method is called for every tuple, the complete method is called when all tuples are processed.

I have put debug sysouts in init and aggregate method.
When I start the topology I can see continuous sysouts from init and aggregate method.
Is this behavior expected ? (Note that there is no data in Kafka)